# Printing 10 values per line

Tags: python, printing

I'm new to python and have a question
I want to print 10 values per line and I can't figure out how to do it. Here's my attempt at it;

```
a = 1
b = 15
count = 0
count_end = 10

while count < count_end:
    while a < b:
        count = count + 1
        print(a, end = " ")
        a = a + 1
        if(count == count_end):
            break
```

The output is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` but I want the output to go from 1 to 10 on one line and then continue from 11 to 15 on a new line under it. I've seen some people use lists to answer a similar question but I don't want to use lists for this question.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you could add another counter for whether to add the line break; also check out the modulo `%` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use one loop, and then check if `count % count_end == 0` to detect every multiple of `count_end`.

```
for count, current in enumerate(range(a, b)):
    print(current, end=" ")
    if count % count_end == 0 or current == b-1:
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 1
b = 15
count = 0
count_end = 10

while count < count_end:
    while a <= b:
        count = count + 1
        print(a, end = " ")
        a = a + 1
        
        if(count == count_end):
            print("")
```

something like this ?

Comment: I appreciate the help but this doesn't really work for a larger input. I belive @Barmar nails it. But thanks again :)